# Why can't I assign variables "b" and "c" on gnome calculator? I get a "malformed expression" error

Tags: gnome, gui, gnome-calculator

Really basic simple stuff. I would like to be able to assign "a", "b", and "c" values to do basic math on Gnome Calculator but I get a "malformed expression" error when trying to assign "b" or "c".

I tried using uppercase and I get the same result. I already looked up the instructions and it says nothing about b or c, only Euler's number and pi and others.

Other letters work fine: a, q, w, etc . . .

Why can't I assign a value to b or c?

Comment: It is not that you can't assign a value to them. You can, by using the `x` button (called _Memory_). However, you can't use them, because of a syntactic error, I am NOT aware of why.